# Get youtube username given a channel id

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

Im trying to get username given the channel ID but the only thing that i get is channel title from snippet and this is not always the same. For instance:

Channel ID: UC2OTNzQ5tsg2eSf-D2mMJ8Q
Channel Title: â–‚â–ƒâ–…â–† Gmanlens29 â–†â–…â–ƒâ–‚
User Name: Gmanlens29

Channel ID: UCgG6-eQtPhAdr3GxYEN0HJw
Channel Title: â–ºâ–ºEdvisssâ—„â—„
User Name: Edwin01230

Is there a way to make this?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to link up with the google+ api, use [status.isLinked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#status.isLinked) for checking if a channel ID is linked to google+ and [contentDetails.googlePlusUserId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId) to snag it.

Comment: Good one. I ended scrapping https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC***** getting <link rel="canonical" href value ...

Answer (score 0):

The channel resource's contentDetails.googlePlusUserId property has been deprecated. Previously, the property was only present if the channel was associated with a Google+ profile. Following the deprecation, the property will no longer be included in any channel resources.